# Make [thread-safety] and [threadsafe] synonyms of [multithreading]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Currently [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-safe) and [other 6 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multithreading/synonyms) are synonyms of [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading).

But [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threadsafe) is synonym of [thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-safety).

[thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-safety) and [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threadsafe) should be made synonyms of [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading).

Comment: Yep, thread-safe should definitely be a synonym for thread-safety...